# How to get the specific key in a dictionary using the just the key's value?

Tags: vimscript, dictionary

Suppose I have a dictionary declared like this:

```
g:dict = {
  \ 'foo' : ['foobar'],
  \ 'bar' : ['barfoo']
\}
```

how can I get the key for `barfoo` using just the value(`barfoo`) itself?

Comment: What happens when multiple keys have the value `barfoo`?

Comment: @muru In my case the keys and values were unique and guaranteed to not have duplicates.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's no function to get a dictionary key from a value, so you'll have to loop over the keys. For example:

```
for [key, value] in items(g:dict)
    if index(value, "barfoo") >= 0
        let g:mykey = key
        break
    endif
endfor

echo g:mykey
```

Comment: Thats exactly what I need! thanks for this!

Answer (score 5):

`echo keys(filter(copy(dict), 'index(v:val, "foobar")>=0'))[0]` should do it

Note it'll be much more efficient than a loop

Comment: you might want to `copy` the dict to prevent it from being changed accidentally

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt but if you copy it, it would no longer be more efficient than simply looping over it, right?

Comment: @muru I am not sure this is true

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt how so? If the goal is to prevent accidental modification, you'd need a full deep copy, and that cannot be faster than simply iterating over a view of those items.

Comment: Even after a copy it s usually faster. Loops are really slow  :(. Thanks for the reminder, i'll fix my answer